# Get the size of a generic array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I've got a generic array like this:

```
T[] array;
array = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
```

and I want to get the size of it later on (it changes).  I've tried `array.size()`, but it throws an error saying `Error: Cannot invoke size() on the array type T[]`.  I've found plenty of posts regarding how to create generic arrays (I know my method does not match most of those, which use `Array.newInstance`) but none regarding using the default methods usually available for arrays.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try array.length instead to get the property 'length'. The size() method would only work with a Collection.

Comment: im just gonna delete this and pretend I was never this dumb

Answer (score 1):

You should ask `array.length` property for the size of array.

The bad news for you - the size of array does not change after you have defined it.
If you want a "dynamic array" try using something from Collections framework. For example `java.util.ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

```
array.length
```

Is the property of the array that returns an int if the size if the array.

If you want a better list, I would use an `ArrayList` where you can use the `size()` method on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
System.out.println(array.length);
```